# Why are triple conjunctions in a resonance forbidden?

Tags: orbit, planet, orbital-mechanics, orbital-resonance, conjunction

I was reading the Wikipedia article about orbital resonance and noticed that [Laplace resonances forbid triple conjunctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_resonance#Laplace_resonance). This seems to be supported by the Io-Europa-Ganymede system and the Nyx-Styx-Hydra moon systems. Why are triple conjunctions forbidden?

I know that the Gliese 876 system has three giant planets who have triple conjunctions, but there are strong gravitational interactions between these planets make the system unstable. So, I would like to confirm, is it possible for three or more non-interacting planets to have a triple conjunction? Have any known examples been discovered?

Comment: lots of math hiding in those relationships.  My quick take is that the stability region depends on being able to reject certain terms in the full equation (unsolvable 3-body problem) due to small masses , as opposed to achieving triple conjunction when those terms are *not* rejected. The latter case is in an unstable region.